# How do I force a link through javascript to an embedded player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I'm trying to figure out what I have to do to make these links(streams) go towards my embedded iframe player. I know that the links have to look like this (twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=destructoid") in-order to work in the player. here is a link to my current code (http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/59/) how can I edit the javascript to make it work?
Thank you for your time!

Current Html:

```
<iframe id="player" name="frame1" type="text/html" width="100" height="100" src="" frameborder="1"></iframe>
<div id="content" class="panel panel-default"></div> 
<div id="list">
    <ul name="ul1">
        <li class="li 1"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Current JS:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=League%20of%20Legends&limit=20&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<div id='list' ><li class='li 1'></li><a href=" + item._links.self + "<div id='content1' >" + item.channel.display_name + " </div></div></a>";
    });
    $("#content").html(temp);
});
```

Here is a link to the api itself, but being new to this I'm having trouble understanding it.(https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/embedding.md#embedding-streams-vods-and-chat)

Comment: Do you mean **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/sing0920/a5MZZ/)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options. You can use the `target` attribute of the anchor link, but note the target attribute is deprecated although it is [supported by all major browsers](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/target).

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player" name="frame1" type="text/html" width="100" height="100" src="" frameborder="1"></iframe>
<div id="content" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="list">
        <ul class="ul1">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=League%20of%20Legends&limit=5&&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<li><a target='frame1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</a></li>";
    });
    $("#list ul").html(temp);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/64/)

Or use jQuery, which is widely regarded as the correct way to do this:

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=League%20of%20Legends&limit=5&&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<li><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'><div id='content1' >" + item.channel.display_name + " </div></a></li>";
    });
    $("#list ul").html(temp);
});

$("#content").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#player").attr('src', this.href);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/66/)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=League%20of%20Legends&limit=5&&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        console.log(item);
        temp = temp + "<div id='list' ><li class='li 1'></li><a href='" + item.channel.url + ".swf' class='vdos'><div id='content1' >" + item.channel.display_name + " </div></div></a>";
    });
    $("#content").html(temp);
});
$(document).on('click', 'a.vdos', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(url);
    $("iframe#player").attr("src", url);
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/60/)